# jqGrid vertical scrollbar

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to have a jqGrid to insert a vertical scrollbar instead of increasing its height as new rows are requested from the pager?

My current code is as follows:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
url:'/someUrl',

datatype:"json",
mtype:'GET',
shrinkToFit:true,
forceFit:true,
autowidth:true,
altRows:true,
cellEdit:true,
altclass:'altRowClass',
multiselect:true,
rowNum:15,
height:300,
rowList:[15, 50, 100, 1000],    
rowNum:15    

});
```

Answer (score 12):

If I correct understand your question you can add CSS like

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv { overflow-y: scroll }
```

to force displaying of the vertical scrollbar in the grid.

Comment: The above answer helped to resolve the issue related to display of vertical scroll bar in jqGrid for IE9 browser.

Comment: This was the only way I could get it to work. `$('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css({ 'overflow-y': 'scroll' });`

Comment: @styfle: What I mean is definition of CSS: `<style type="text/css">.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv { overflow-y: scroll }</style>`. Declarative CSS works more quickly as setting `style` attribute on `<table>`. In general the results should be the same.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
 scrollerbar:true
 height:"200"
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick:

```
.ui-jqgrid-bdiv{
    max-height: 340px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vertical scroll

```
gridComplete: function () {
                $('#gbox_workshopPersonGrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css({ 'height': '100%', 'max-height': '450px', 'overflow-y': 'scroll', 'overflow-x': 'hidden' });
            }
```

note: workshopPersonGrid is your grid name