# How to display vertical scroll bar in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

Currently I am working on a task which uses jqGrid. I need to show a vertical scroll bar withing the jqGrid.

```
$('#user-list').jqGrid({
            height: "auto",
            width: "590",
            url: getUsersForClientGroupUrl + "?random=" + Math.random(),
            rowNum: 10,
            mtype: 'POST',
            viewrecords: false,
            postData: { testGroup: gettestGroupId(), active: true },
            datatype: 'json',
            colNames: ['testGroupID', 'Login', 'Role'],
            pgbuttons: false,
            pgtext: null,
            viewrecords: false,
            colModel: [
                { name: 'testGroupID', index: 'testGroupID', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Login', index: 'Login', search: false, width: 130 },
                { name: 'Role', index: 'Role', search: false, width: 100 }
            ],
            caption: "Users for test group: " + gettestGroupName(),
            pager: '#users-pager',
            ondblClickRow: function (userId) {
                editUser(userId);
            },
            sortname: 'Login',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            loadui: 'enable',
            loadError: function (xhr, status) {
                location.reload();
            }
        })
```

**

- Image Details:

**

[image]

Can any one help me in resolving the issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below url helped me to resolve the issue.
[jqGrid vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502628/jqgrid-vertical-scrollbar)

Thanks a lot for the help provided Charles Mighty

Answer (score 0):

vertical scroll bar appears when the grid is larger than the space allotted, so in your case change height from auto to whatever you like play with size and you should have your vertical scroll bar, remember reduce the height from what it is currently

Comment: I tried to play with various combination of height attribute and set the scroll:true, but it is not working for IE9 and chrome browser. Can you please tell me whether I am missing out any other settings in the jqGrid.